# How can I run multiple instances of a service concurrently in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

Currently, I am trying to create a console application in .NET 7, which is able to run multiple instances of a service concurrently.

The `Program.cs` file looks like this:

```cs
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ConsoleHostedService>();
            services.AddScraperServices();
        })
        .RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

where `AddScraperServices()` looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddScraperServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IScrapingService, ScrapingService>();

    services.AddScoped(provider => new SemaphoreSlim(2));

    return services;
}
```

and the ConsoleHostedService like this:

```
internal sealed class ConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    // .. properties and constructor here

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

                    try
                    {
                        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                        {
                            var scrapingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScrapingService>();

                            await scrapingService.ScrapeAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception!");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _semaphore.Release();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The ScrapingSerivce, which is used in the ConsoleHostedService looks like this:

```cs
public class ScrapingService : IScrapingService
{
    // .. properties and constructor here

    public async Task ScrapeAsync()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, Semaphore should now create two instances of ScrapingService running parallel to each other. Spoiler: It does not.

It might be important to mention, that Semaphore should create a new instance, if there is one beeing finished. That means, that I always want the count of instances equal the maximum count of instances.

Does anybody knows, where my problem is? I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Semaphore` should now create two instances of `ScrapingService` running parallel to each other

Probably just a nitpick and me being pedantic - `SemaphoreSlim` does not start anything it is just a primitive used for synchronization.

As far as I can see in `ConsoleHostedService.StartAsync` you are starting only one task which runs an endless loop which awaits every invocation of `ScrapeAsync` - `await scrapingService.ScrapeAsync();` so the next iteration will not start until the current one is finished, so no parallel invocations here.

Personally I would not even bother with the semaphore, and just used some setting to determine the parallelism and passed it to the hosted service (also I would have used `BackgroundService` over `IHostedService`, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class)). Something along these lines:

```cs
class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MyBackgroundServiceSettings _settings;

    public MyBackgroundService(MyBackgroundServiceSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, _settings.ParallelCount)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }))
            .ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

If for some reason there is a possibility that `ScrapingService` is resolved somewhere else in the app (though I would suggest to avoid that) and you still want to limit it's concurrent invocations - then I hugely recommend to abstract over the `SemaphoreSlim` (something like `IScrapingServiceLimiter`, maybe use ) to avoid the `services.AddScoped(provider => new SemaphoreSlim(2));` registration (which looks a bit strange to me, TBH).

P.S.

Also I would recommend to pass the `CancellationToken stoppingToken` and use it in `IScrapingService.ScrapeAsync` with corresponding changes to the code.

Comment: I love the idea with the background service - Now everything is working fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: In case the code represented by `// ...` fails, one task will complete as faulted but the other tasks will continue running. The service will keep running with a reduced degree of parallelism. Is this behavior desirable?

Comment: @MaikHasler Theodor makes a good point - be sure that handler is fault-tolerant.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In my case, it would be absolutly okay to have a reduced degree of parallelism. Anyways, there might be someone, who needs another, more fault-tolerant option. Maybe you want to add yours, if you have one in mind :)

Comment: @MaikHasler quite the opposite. I would advice in favor of a completely fault-intolerant implementation, where a single faulted worker would cause the immediate cancellation of all other workers, followed by the termination of the process. I don't think that a process with few, or half, or all but one, workers dead is a healthy situation.